# Mysql to Php, problems with german,swedish,icelandic etc letters

Tags: php, mysql

I am not very experienced with database and php and I have a problem.

I have made a simple database in `phpadmin` on a webserver with a table called `NEWS` with 3 columns called `int ID`, `text RUBRIK`, `text ARTICLE`.

When i use `SELECT * FROM NEWS the result from ID and RUBRIK` works well but the result from `ARTICLE` returns `"null"`. Do anyone know what is wrong.

In phpmyadmin it works perfect to add column with text that contains the swedish letters and in phpmyadmin it is possible to see the stored text in a correct way, it  is when the text is called to the php it wont work.

I use a `index.php` file interact with the database, because `index.php` is just working for connecting my android application with the database the answer from `index.php` is `print(json_encode($output));`

PS, I have tried saving the `index.php` file in MS Notes with `ANSI` and `UTF-8` coding. Makes no difference, I have tried manipulating my database by changing all collations I can find in the `phpmyadmin` between `latin1_general_ci`, `utf8_general_ci`, `utf8_general_bin`, `utf8_swedish` etc etc.
I have also tried the command `mysql_query("set names utf8");` which I was recommended to try, using that made the database return the letters in the similar to `"/&aumi"`.

Would really appreciate if anyone could help me.

Here is the php file.

```
<?php 
   $con = mysql_connect("mysqlserver","user","passwords");

   if(!$con)
   {
       die(' funkar ej: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   mysql_select_db("database", $con);

   $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM NEWS");

   while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))  
       $output[]=$e;

   print(json_encode($output));

   mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding inside the php with `utf8_encode ( string $data )` Encoding each `$e` with it.

Comment: not sure that will work, because $e is an array and `utf8_encode()` will only accept strings.

Comment: it can be done with one `for` iterating each value inside the `$e`. The point is he needs the encoding :D

Comment: I changed the code and it returned "\u00e5\u00e4\u00e4" instead of "åäö"

Comment: What you are planing to do with the JSON output? If you are using with JAVA `decode` the response using URLDecoder.decode(response, HTTP.UTF-8) and you'll have your letters as you want.

Comment: I changed the code and it returned "\u00e5\u00e4\u00e4" instead of "åäö" <?php 


$con = mysql_connect("databaseserver","user","password");
if(!$con)
{
 die(' funkar ej: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("database", $con);

 
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");


 $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM NEWS");



while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) //assoc
{
 utf8_encode($e);
        $output[]=$e;
}

utf8_encode($e);
 
print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();

?>

Comment: I am going to use it with android.

Comment: Good. Then you can use what I said before `URLDecoder.decode(responseString, HTTP.UTF-8)` it doesnt mean if it says URL :P , you'll use it just for decoding the `\u00e5\u00e4\u00e4`. So to wrap up. You get the response to your android, make a string , decode the string, and you are done.

Comment: Gonna try that right away, just waiting for my webbserver to wake up, problems logging in. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

with `json_encode()` you need to use `utf8_encode()`
and you have to force use utf8, just before your `mysql_query()`, like so `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`

Comment: I tried the mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); but it did not return the swedish letter as "å,ä,ö" it returned them as html code something like \&auld, dont remember the exact combination but i think its the html code for the letters.

Comment: yes. I'm returning swedish letters too, and the letter "ö" will return as "\u00f6" when you use `json_encode()`. it'll be converted back to "ö" when you decode it.
**EDIT:** i'm sure you know this, but use `var_dump($output)` to dump the array and you'll see the correct letters.

Comment: gonna try to use it from the android application. Problems to log in to my webbserver at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just change the collation type, you should also change the default character set for the DB table. Also, DO use 'set names utf8'.